# Rails 5.2 counter_cache throwing up SQLException: no such column error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic `blog`/`comments` situation in my app and am trying to create a "most commented blogs" section in my app.

I have this for my `comment.rb` model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :blog, optional: true, counter_cache: true
end
```

And this in my `blogs_controller.rb`:

```
@commented_blogs = Blog.where("published_on <= ?", Date.today).order('comments_count DESC').limit(3)
```

Yet when I try to iterate over `@commented_blogs` in the view, I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comments_count: SELECT  "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE (published_on <= '2018-12-06') ORDER BY comments_count DESC LIMIT ?
```

I feel like I need to add a column to the database, but the documentation I looked at didn't mention any migrations.  Can anyone help?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

Here's my schema for `blogs` and `comments`:

```
  create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "teaser"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "category", default: "General"
    t.string "linked_module"
    t.boolean "published", default: false
    t.datetime "published_on"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "image_id"
    t.integer "pdf_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.string "cta_read_more", default: "Read More"
    t.string "cta_pdf", default: "Get My Free PDF"
    t.string "cta_video", default: "Watch the Video"
    t.string "convertkit_data_form_toggle"
    t.string "convertkit_href"
    t.integer "pin_image_id"
    t.string "data_pin_description"
    t.string "freebie_filename"
    t.string "video_link"
    t.string "freebie_type", default: "File"
    t.string "freebie_description"
    t.index ["image_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_image_id"
    t.index ["pdf_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_pdf_id"
    t.index ["pin_image_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_pin_image_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_blogs_on_slug", unique: true
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "blog_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "approved", default: false
    t.boolean "read", default: false
    t.string "email"
    t.string "name"
    t.index ["blog_id"], name: "index_comments_on_blog_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
  end
```

Comment: Please add the schema.rb file.
And if you are specifying that you are referring to some reference you need to mention in the question.

Comment: I have replied to your question please check

Comment: @MohammadShahnawaz I also added the schema for `blogs` and `comments` to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with the `counter_cache`, you do need to add a `comments_count` column to your blogs table [(as is indicated in the documentation)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache):

> Although the :counter_cache option is specified on the model that
>   includes the belongs_to declaration, the actual column must be added
>   to the associated (has_many) model. In the case above, you would need
>   to add a column named books_count to the Author model.

If you do not want to store the `comments_count` (i.e. get rid of the `counter_cache`), you can go with the solution that the other answer mentioned, which computes the `comments_count` on the fly:

```
@commented_blogs = Blog.left_outer_joins(:comments).select('blogs.*, count(comments.*) as comments_count').group(:id).order(comments_count: :desc).limit(3)
```